# Cannot boot into Windows 10

Tags: updates, windows

I have dual boot of Window 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on one hard drive. After some Windows updates I cannot boot into Windows. I have to boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. Occasionally, Windows will roll back updates. But since last update I cannot boot into Windows 10 at all, even `sudo update-grub` does not help. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you select the boot entry from the grub menu for booting into Windows, what do you get (any error message/blue screen etc.)? Also if you have tried `boot-repair` tool then paste the link of result here.

Comment: One way: u can recover Windows using Windows repair disk and then reinstall grub for Ubuntu access. There are already few Tutorials on how to do it. before that try pressing some f12 like  key to pop up boot menu option and see if windows boot manager is there or not if yes select it.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht. I do not get any messages after selecting Windows option in grub. I get a bit redish screen as if Ubuntu is getting ready to boot. I will try `boot-repair` tool.

Comment: @user1700890 Yes, try boot-repair first. Most of the boot related problems are easily solved by this tool.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht I tried `sudo boot-repair`, but got back `sudo: boot-repair: command not found`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Please follow the instructions given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht, Thank you, it worked! I now have two Windows 10 booting option `sda1` and `sda2`, but one of them works well. After `boot-repair`, I also ran `update-grub` and everything worked

Comment: Happy to know that your problem has been solved. :) By the way, can you provide the details of what you are saying about two option? I think that too can be rectified.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht, thank you again! Now Grub loading options are:  `ubuntu`, `advandced options for ubuntu`,  `windows 10 (loaded) (on /dev/sda1)`, `windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)` Windows 10 on sda1 load s just fine.

Comment: That's good. :)